# What am I doing wrong in this PL/SQL statement?

Tags: oracle, plsql, syntax-error

Can anyone help me with what I'm doing wrong in this small statement?

```
declare

   cursor emp_cursor is 
    select employee_id, quantity * salary AS price 
      from employees;

   emp_row emp_cursor%rowtype;

begin

   open emp_cursor;

   if (price < 2,000)
      then price := 2,000 * 0.15;
   else if (price >= 2,000)
      then price := 2,000 * 0.20; 
      loop
         fetch emp_cursor into emp_row;
         exit when emp_cursor%notfound;
         dbms_output.put_line(emp_row.employee_id || ' ' || emp_row.price);
      end loop;

   close emp_cursor;

end;
```

I'm using pl/sql developer.

Comment: Think about what you're doing... when you first access `price` where did you get that from? Adding indentation helps a lot as well...

Comment: When writing a question if you could always include error messages and an idea of what you're trying to that'd be fantastic as well. Thanks!

Comment: The program doesn't really make sense. What are you hoping to do?

Comment: This does not make any sense. What is the **real** problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: What you're doing wrong is not reading the error messages that tell you that your syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the ',' in your comparisons:

```
if (price < 2,000)
```

is a syntax error. If you meant 2E0, simply write 2, if you meant 2E3, write 2000.

Comment: Where did I write that 2,000 is valid or recommended using it?

Answer (score 1):

1. You must not use a thousand delimiter. Write IF price < 2000 instead of IF price < 2,000.
2. You forgot an END IF;

Answer (score 0):

Your price should be emp_row.price. And put your if after exit when... You have to open, fetch cursor first. Then process rows and close the cursor. The code is cleaner when you user a variable instead of emp_row.price. For ex, if emp_row.price < 2000 - then v_price:= 2000 * 0.15... And get rid of commas in your numbers.

```
 loop
     fetch emp_cursor into emp_row;
     exit when emp_cursor%notfound;

     if (emp_row.price < 2000) then....
      ....
     end if;
     dbms_output.put_line(emp_row.employee_id || ' ' || emp_row.price);
  end loop;
  ....
```